# How to have a monthly Box Whisker Plots for a time series dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn

I have a dataframe for 2 years on hourly basis

```
>>> print(df.head())
                     Time    X
    0 2004-01-07 00:00:00    9.25  
    1 2004-01-07 01:00:00    9.25  
    2 2004-01-07 02:00:00    9.25  
    3 2004-01-07 03:00:00    9.25 
    4 2004-01-07 04:00:00    9.25

>>> print(df.tail())
                 Time   X  
0 2005-11-27 22:00:00   875.0   
1 2005-11-27 23:00:00   875.0 
2 2005-11-28 00:00:00   875.0 
3 2005-11-28 01:00:00   875.0   
4 2005-11-28 02:00:00   875.0
```

I want to have the box whisker plots for the individual months all in one figure using the seaborn. I tried to group them by this line of code:

```
M = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['Time'], freq="M"))
```

I have tried many codes found on stackoverflow and web, but cannot figure it out what is the right way to plot them. The `Time` column is `datetime64` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Get the month from df
df["Month"] = df["Time"].dt.month

# Group by month
monthly_groups = df.groupby("Month")

# Plotting Part
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6)) 
sns.boxplot(x="Month", y="X", data=df)
plt.title("Box Whisker Plots for Individual Months")
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.ylabel("X")
plt.xticks(range(1, 13), calendar.month_name[1:])
plt.show()
```

Second solution based on your new spesification on the comment:

```
df["Year_Month"] = df["Time"].dt.to_period("M")
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6)) 
sns.boxplot(x="Year_Month", y="X", data=df)
plt.title("Box Whisker Plots for Individual Months")
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.ylabel("X")
plt.xticks(rotation=45) #Optional for better readability 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Let me know if this works out for you or if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.  There is a problem. I have 23 months, but this method takes all similar months as one group. I am looking to have one box plot for example for January 2004 and one for January 2005. so, I am looking to have a sequence of 23 months.

Comment: @PSB I have added a second solution that should solve that problem, try it out and let me know if it solves your issue :)